# NodeJs stress testing tools/methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, stress-testing

I've searched a lot about stress testing a NodeJs application/module but I didn't find anything.

I have a push server application (something like socket.io) and I want to test it to ensuring there's no memory leaks and that it exhibits optimal performance.

What's the best method or tools for doing that?

Comment: i've used [funckload](http://funkload.nuxeo.org), it is written in python and has nice benchmarks, and [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/). You also can find some nice posts like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492/how-do-you-stress-test-a-web-application) too. Hope this will help

Comment: Here you can find some code developed for benchamrking Node + Socket.IO: https://github.com/Weswit/Lightstreamer-toolkit-socket.io-benchmark

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You do not need any special tool for load testing Node.js application. You can use any load test tools:

- [ApacheBench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)
- [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/)
- [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

From opensource and free tools I can recommend JMeter. As it has built-in Proxy Server which can [record HTTP traffic](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server). Advantage of JMeter than other tools is user friendly GUI. You can find article related Node.js load balancing and [JMeter testing](http://mazira.com/blog/introduction-load-balancing-nodejs/).

Comment: Look: http://strongloop.com/ It is special for Node.js and payment, but has its trial version.

Comment: I used JMETER and found that Nodejs can handle upto 1000 request , I am using windows server 2012 with 8 gb RAM intel XEON

Answer (score 3):

Try this [phanos](https://npmjs.org/package/phanos) stress test tool. This is phantomjs based tool, and you can loading ajax request too with it. But this tool doesn't provide stat info, you should use nodetime (or something else) for analyze the traffic performance.

Comment: It's generally good SO etiquette to indicate that you wrote the software that you're promoting. Otherwise it looks interesting.